# WebdriverIO | how to show html content of wdio-timeline-reporter or wdio-html-reporter generated file with css in the email body sent by nodemailer

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nodemailer, webdriver-io

I am trying to send the html content of the file (report.html in the pic below) and this file opens up in browser perfectly as the reference of css works fine when opening it from the folder. But when I am trying to send this file as html body using nodemailer it just loses all its styling and in email I am just receiving a plain text email just like below.

[image: Report.html file]

[image: report-style reference in html]

[image: email content]

Can someone tell me how to tell nodemailer that all the css are present of this file is present in the html-reports folder and it should appear in the email body same as it opens up in the browser.

If anyone using WDIO and sharing any such information over email then please share this info with me.

I am using latest version of the WDIO btw viz. V7.7 (cucumber framework)

Basically I want to achieve below use case -

1. After running the test html report comes of all the cucumber scenario pass/fail/skipped along with error trace
2. I want to share this info in email body and not as attachment and my email body should be properly styled

Thanks much in advance !

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the results that you mentioned you have to use [internal CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp), this is placed in the `head` section of your `report.html`, within a `style` element.

So where you have the link to your external CSS you want to replace that with the actual CSS that is in the `report-styles.css` and place it in a style element.

**`report-styles.css`**:

```
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```

**`report.html` before**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="report-styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div>Your report</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Replace the CSS link with the actual CSS in the file

**`report.html` after**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
    h1 {
     color: blue;
    }
    p {
     color: red;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

   <div>Your report</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Then you can add the `report.html` to your email and all the styles will be there without having to reference that external file.

---

This will require some additional coding on your end after your report is completed and before you send your email.

You can use something like gulp to do the replacement for you or write your own code for the replacement.

[`gulp.js` example:](https://codeburst.io/how-to-inject-css-code-into-an-html-page-d3feb5c85b2b)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var fs = require('fs');

function getCSSFilename(linkTag) {
  var hrefValue = /href\=\"([A-Za-z0-9/._]*)\"/g;
  var cssFilename = linkTag.match(hrefValue);
  cssFilename = cssFilename[0].replace("href=\"", "").replace("\"", "");
  return cssFilename;
}

gulp.task('inject-styles', function () {
  return gulp.src("./report/report.html")
      .pipe(replace(/<link rel="stylesheet" href="[^"]*"*>/g, function(linkTag) {
          var style = fs.readFileSync(`.${getCSSFilename(linkTag)}`, 'utf8');
          return '<style>\n' + style + '\t</style>';
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./report'));
});
```

Hope this is helpful enough to let you know how you achieve what you described.